# Cross-browser support of HTMLFormElement.elements

Tags: javascript, forms, browser, cross-browser

I am curious to know what is the actual browser support of `HTMLFormElement.elements` across the main browsers? What about IE8?

Comment: Check the Browser Compatibility table at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement. It doesn't indicate any compatibility issues.

Comment: @Barmar, yes I checked it out, but there is no any information on minimal supported web browser versions.

Comment: If they don't list a minimum version, it implies all versions.

Comment: Actually @ezpresso this one's likely the compatibility table you were looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection